# Word VBA macro which moves all anchors to top of floating image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some large documents with +50 images each. The problem is that most of them are floating images. Position is good but images are anchored in wrong places (most often to the last line on the page). I want to move all anchors to the position where its picture is floating.

(Preciser description, from comments: I want to read the position of the image and move its anchor to this place. So if an image is in the middle of page 3 and its anchor is at the bottom of page 3, I want to move anchor to middle of this page. And do the same thing for all images.)

Is it possible?

I cannot make them inline, it will change structure of my documents.
I've tried to move them by some value but macro does not change anchor's position.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, vPos As Single, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Shapes(i)
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage: vPos = .Top
      With .Anchor
        If .Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) > vPos Then
          Set Rng = .Paragraphs.First.Range
          Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
          With Rng
            Do While .Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Last.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) < vPos
              .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
            Loop
            .Collapse wdCollapseStart
          End With
          Rng.FormattedText = .FormattedText
          .Delete
        End If
      End With
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution is magnificent! I couldn't ask for more. Thank you for help. With this my macro is complete. @macropod