# Deleting Empty Paragraphs in Word - but not objects/pictures

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I'm using the macro from @Wayne G. Dunn on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318849/19745654) and it works great, but it doesn't understand when there are pictures/objects in my document and deletes them.

Would there be any way around it?

The said document is a Word file exported from an online app/software we use at work, if it helps. I don't know the specs of the picture.

Comment: I used Dunn's code on test document with empty paragraphs and embedded images and it worked without deleting the images. Are you embedding the images in textboxes?  What kind of objects do you have embedded?

Comment: I just use a find and replace, replacing _^p^p_ with _^p_. No VBA needed.

Comment: @PeterT I don't do anything with them myself. They are organizational charts generated through the app. It seems to me like an image but who knows what MS really consider it as. The image ribbon appear when I click on it, but can't do much with it besides resizing. All I know is that it "floats" on the page and isn't sitting an a real line (sorry I'm French, don't know the real MS term for it. LOL).

Comment: Thanks @JohnKorchok, I wish it could have been that simple. In my case though, it doesn't remove every empty paragraphs as Dunn's code, have no idea why. Also, I use a macro in a personnalized ribbon so that people can easily use it without having to know the find/replace function. But thank you again for your suggestion.

Comment: ^p^p finds 2 paragraph marks in a row. If the second paragraph mark has a space or tab before it (surprisingly common), the find and replace won't work. Neither will Macropod's answer below. So your macro should do more than one find, to cover the common scenarios like a space (^p ^p) or tab (^p^t^p). If you turn on the hidden formatting characters in Word, it will give you a better idea of which combinations of characters are typical in your documents.

Comment: Since your images may be floating (but still anchored to a paragraph), the solution may be to "reset" the images to anchor to their relative position on the page. That way when you delete empty paragraphs, the images should stay in place. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789712/4717755) for a solution to reset the image anchor to the page and then run your empty paragraph routine after that.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your linked thread is awful and is indeed liable to delete shapes attached to paragraphs. There is also no need to loop through every paragraph. Indeed, a macro isn't even needed for most cases. All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = [^13]{2,}
Replace = ^p
```

As a macro, this becomes:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[^13]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** For systems using non-english regional settings, you may need to use:

```
[^13]{2;}
```

instead of:

```
[^13]{2,}
```

in both the Find/Replace and the macro.